# Regasm and Heat - how it works

Tags: wix, wix3.8, regasm

I have a general question. If I need to deploy an assembly as part of my product, which needs to be registered on a client machine and the tlb file created, people suggest to use WiX toolset's heat harvesting tool.

However, do I need to register (regasm) that assembly initially on my PC in order first to run the heat tool on that file and get all necessary data (registries) related to it and then when the final msi package will be ready including that data for the file when installing it will put all that back on client's machine? Or perhaps I don't need to register that assembly on my developer's machine, and I just run heat on the regular assembly file, but heat knows auto-magically and generates the necessary registry data for the file later to be installed on client's machine and be registered as regasm?

Can you confirm that the same idea and technique applies on when registering COM component using the regsvr32.exe? Again do I need to register the COM component on my developers machine first before including the heat's generated data related to that component into my installation package, or there is no need to register the component on my PC prior to run the heat on it?

Answer (score 1):

> > do I need to register (regasm) that assembly initially on my PC

NO. I tested this. You don't need to run regasm if you checked "Register for COM Interop" setting in your .NET build settings, which will create TLB for you.

Otherwise, you could run **REGASM /TLB** to create the TLB.

> > but heat knows auto-magically

YES. You must run HEAT on the TLB and DLL.

> > Can you confirm that the same idea and technique applies on when registering COM component using the regsvr32.exe?

YES

> > Again do I need to register the COM component on my developers machine first

No. I didn't test this.

Comment: Thanks, and moreover, not only that I don't need to register any component prior to harvesting the reg data for it, during the harvesting the tool doesn't register that component. However, I'd like to know if the tool can harvest the tlb related reg data as well if I don't initially regasm /tlb it to create the tlb file?